# Difference between n_times and chain

Tags: functional-programming

I came across the following two function definitions:

```
function n_times(f, n) {
    if (n === 1) {return f;}
    else {
        return function(x) {
            return f((n_times(f, n - 1)) (x));
        }
    }
}

function chain(f, n) {
    if(n === 1) {
        return f;
    } else {
        return (chain(f, n - 1)) (f);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the difference between the two. Applying the substitution model suggests the following:

for `chain`: `chain(f, 3) (x) = f(f(f(x))))`

for `n_times`: `n_times(f, 3) (x) = f((f(f(x))) (x))`

So there are more than one variable in the case of `n_times`.

Answer (score 3):

You must have gone wrong somewhere in your substitution. With the function definitions you gave (which are not really standard btw), it's

```
  n_times(f, 3) (x)
≡ function(x) { return f(n_times(f, 2)(x)) } (x)
≡ f(n_times(f, 2)(x))
≡ f(function(x) { return f(n_times(f, 1)(x)) } (x))
≡ f(f(n_times(f, 1)(x)))
≡ f(f(f(x)))
```

and

```
  chain(f, 3) (x)
≡ chain(f, 2) (f) (x)
≡ chain(f, 1) (f) (f) (x)
≡ f (f) (f) (x)
```

Comment: I see, I must have messed up somewhere. But in either case are the two equivalent? Thank you

Comment: No, obviously not, they expand to something different. Also consider what type `f` would need to have in the two expressions.